# Recursive directory listing - possible limitation issue

Tags: batch-file, directory, file-listing

I run this script every night:

```
dir /s x:\>"X:\Back-Ups\File Lists\X-Drive-Complete-File-List.txt"
```

However the server has grown a lot since I first put it in place and I have hit a limitation. The file output stops at line 1002991, which is about half way.

I can't set it up for individual folders as the folders change frequently.

Is there anyway around this?

Comment: Does perhaps the folder disappear the script is currently enumerating? `dir` itself doesn't have a limit for the output, as far as I know, but there can be factors where it may simply crash. Alternatively you could try `powershell -noprofile -command "gci -rec X:\ | % FullName"` instead of `dir /s X:\` to see whether it makes a difference in how you enumerate things.

Comment: As a side note, `Dir /S` will not create a `Complete-File-List`; to include everything you'd need to incorporate the `/A` option. See `Dir /?` for usage information.

Answer (score 0):

*"I can't set it up for individual folders as the folders change frequently."*

Yes you can:

```
for /d %%a in (X:\*) do (
    dir /s /b /a "%%a" > "X:\Back-Ups\File Lists\X-Drive-Complete-File-List.txt"
)
```

The parenthesis are not needed here, I purely used them to split the text into readable form. it can be just:

```
for /d %%a in (X:\*) do dir /s /b /a "%%a" > "X:\Back-Ups\File Lists\X-Drive-Complete-File-List.txt"
```

Comment: @Compo yeah I will remove, not sure why I even checked the existence. It however does read `if exist "%%a"` without the \

Answer (score 0):

As a potential alternative, it may be worth seeing how `RoboCopy` does.

```bat
RoboCopy X:\ Null /S /ZB /COPY:D /XJ /R:0 /W:0 /L /FP /NS /NC /NDL /NP /LOG:"%~dp0X-Drive-Complete-File-List.txt" /NJH /NJS
```

*It should be run As administrator*